Date Factorial Calculation
Objective
Given a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD, calculate the factorial of the sum of the digits in the date.
Input: A single line containing a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD.
Output: The factorial of the sum of the digits in the date.
Functionality Overview:
The formula used to achieve this is:
=IF(ISDATE(A1), LET(t, SUBSTITUTE(A1, "-", ""), FACT(SUM(0 + REGEXEXTRACT(t, REPT("(.)", LEN(t)))))))

Key Components:

Date Validation: The formula begins with ISDATE(A1), which checks if the value in cell A1 is a valid date. This ensures that
calculations are performed only on valid date inputs.
Substituting Characters: The LET function defines a variable t, which substitutes hyphens in the date string with empty strings,
allowing for easier manipulation of the date components.
Extracting Digits: The REGEXEXTRACT function extracts individual digits from the modified date string using a regular expression.
Calculating Factorial: The SUM(0 + ...) construct converts the extracted digits into numbers, which are then summed. The FACT
function calculates the factorial of this sum.

Handling Various Date Scenarios

Leap Year Dates: The formula can handle dates like February 29 in leap years, as it validates the date format before performing
calculations.

End-of-Month Dates: It can also manage end-of-month scenarios, ensuring that dates like April 30 or June 30 are processed
correctly.

Invalid Date Formats: If the input date is in an invalid format, the ISDATE function will return false, preventing further
calculations and thus avoiding errors.


Objective Winning Criteria:
Total Score Based on Code Length and Correctness
Score Calculation: The score will be determined by the formula:
\$Score = \frac{(Correct Outputs) * (Max Code Length)}{(Total Test Cases)} - (Code Length)\$

Correct Outputs: Count of test cases that the solution passes.

Total Test Cases: The total number of test cases provided.

Max Code Length: The length of the longest code submission (to normalize scores).

Code Length: The length of the participant's code in bytes.


Test Cases

Valid Dates:

Input: 2024-11-29
Output: 51090942171709440000
Explanation: The sum of the digits (2 + 0 + 2 + 4 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 9 = 21) is used to compute the factorial (21! = 51,090,942,171,709,440,000).



Leap Year Dates

Input: 2024-02-29
Output: 51090942171709440000
Explanation: Valid leap year date; sum of digits is 21.



End-of-Month Dates

Input: 2024-04-30
Output: 265252859812191058636308480000000
Explanation: The sum of the digits (2 + 0 + 2 + 4 + 0 + 4 + 3 + 0 = 15) is used to compute the factorial (15! = 1,307,674,368,000).



Invalid Dates

Input: 2024-02-30
Output: Error or Invalid Date
Explanation: February 30 does not exist.

Input: 2024-13-01
Output: Error or Invalid Date
Explanation: Month 13 is invalid.



Edge Cases

Input: 0000-01-01
Output: 1
Explanation: The sum of the digits (0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 2) is used to compute the factorial (2! = 2).

Input: 2021-12-31
Output: 4796001600


Explanation: The sum of the digits (2 + 0 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 1 = 12) is used to compute the factorial (12! = 479,001,600).


Worked Example

Input: 2024-11-29
Output: 51090942171709440000
Explanation: The sum of the digits (2 + 2 + 4 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 9 = 21) is used to compute the factorial (21! =  51,090,942,171,709,440,000)

Input: 2024-02-29
Output: 51090942171709440000
Explanation: The sum of the digits (2 + 2 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 9 = 21) is used to compute the factorial (21! =  51,090,942,171,709,440,000)


Additional Considerations

Ensure to handle edge cases, such as invalid date formats or dates
that do not exist (e.g., 2024-02-30).
Provide example inputs and outputs to illustrate the expected behavior of the solution
Consider using MathJax for any mathematical expressions to ensure they are displayed correctly.

I/O format
Flexible; default I/O policies apply.

Welcome to Code Golf! This site is for competitive programming challenges, not general issues. You may want to check out Stack Overflow, although be sure to read their "how to ask" page first.

@emanresuA Edited the question to ask about a competitive challenge.

@Arunabh is this a code golf challenge? if not I think you need an Objective Scoring Criteria

I've voted not to reopen this question, for two reasons. Firstly, as pointed out, this needs an objective scoring criteria to have any chance of being reopened. But, more importantly, the "Solution Approach". Not only is this an unobservable requirement (how are you confirming people are using e.g. binary search?) but it indicates heavily to me that this is a homework question, or otherwise non-original, as requiring this style of specific steps to solving the challenge is a classic hallmark of those questions.

@Arunabh there's a sandbox that has been very useful for many posters. It certainly was of great benefit to me when I posted a challenge.

Why do you keep changing the challenge? From what I can tell, this is the 3rd or 4th challenge you've edited this to be?

@cairdcoinheringaahing Every time the question is being left closed in review. So, I am changing the challenge just to force the question to reopen.

That won't result in the question being reopened. The challenge will be reopened when it's at a standard required on the site. By changing the task every other day, you're having to restart getting the challenge up to the required quality. You're more likely to get the challenge reopened by sticking to one specification and improving that as suggested

Also, the leap year challenge is a duplicate

@cairdcoinheringaahing Even after making edits based on the suggestions from the Meta question, the question is still not reopening, so I am getting indignant.

I've reviewed this a couple times, but it's been missing an objective winning criterion. That's the main obstacle to having it reopened.

You've completely changed the challenge over the course of edits. If you have a different challenge you will probably get better results if you sandbox the idea and post a separate question. That way you don't start of with a bunch of downtown from an old version of the question.

As it stands though, I think the new challenge is essentially a duplicate of the existing factorial challenge.

This challenge's most recent incarnation seems trivial in any language that has suitable built-ins. E.g., in a spreadsheet you'd just do =dec2bin(fact(A1)). The "recursive or iterative" requirements seems non-observable.

This challenge's now most recent incarnation seems trivial. E.g., in a spreadsheet you'd just do ="Days between: "&B1-A1&" "&trim(B1)&" is a weekend: "&if(weekday(B1,2)>5,"Yes","No"), which would handle the specified date format, leap years, different month lengths and so on.

In the jargon of the site "objective winning criterion" is a method to score valid answers against each other. This challenge still requires an objective winning criterion.

It feels like you are using the reopen queue to sandbox a question. It's not really designed for this and it's hard to give constructive feedback this way. There's a link to the sandbox above. I strongly suggest that you put create a challenge in the sandbox, and when complete post a new challenge. This challenge is old and has a negative score, if it is reopened it will be algorithmically suppressed. You will have a smoother process if you sandbox and create a new challenge. Feel free to ping me on the sandbox, or in chat.I have written >300 challenges I generally know what succeeds.

As far as the current state goes, I'm not entirely clear on what the winning criterion means. Are the test cases all possible dates? I'm also not sure if this really counts as a WC since it's pretty easy to just get a perfect score. We generally recommend people stick to the standard WCs e.g. code-gplf for their first challenge. However if you change it to just be code-gplf it's likely to be a duplicate since the core task is the same as the factorial challenge. (Sorry, It's hard to find the link from the review queue.) ping me in chat or the sandbox and I can try to help you.

@WheatWizard I am getting mad now that you are every time closing this without giving an explanation in the comments for every edit I make.

The explanation remains the same. It is not clear what the objective winning criterion is. There seem to be multiple vague criteria. I can answer any questions and link to meta posts, but I don't quite know what to say otherwise.

@WheatWizard I have refined the approach to the objective winning criteria. This structured approach will help participants focus on the key aspects of their submissions and understand the evaluation process better.

There are still 5 criteria, which are still vaue rather than objective. It needs a single objective way to score answers.

@WheatWizard This is now a a clear, objective scoring system that balances both the correctness of the solution and the efficiency of the code length, making it easier to determine a winner based on a single score.

What are the test cases? The scoring mentions test cases.

@WheatWizard Added the test cases.
